# What to if i made changes to production.env in mydjango website .Google gives timeout error when i load my website

Tags: python, django

I turn debug=true and add 127.0.0.1 to allowed host list in production.env and run the python manage.py runserver command to connect to the local host. It worked fine. But later when change the debug to false and removed 127.0.0.1 from allowedhost list and try to reach my site on google it gives time out error. What should i do to get my site up run in google or production server? Is there some django or python command to restore the site to previous state? Im new to Django

Comment: Add error screenshot here?

Comment: Most likely it's your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting ...

Comment: @GRVPrasad -- i searched the google for the site and it show timeout err. after making the debug = false nd clearing the 27.0.0. from the allowedhost should i run some command to save the changes or make the server understand that this is the final production changes?

Comment: @urbanespaceman how do i check it?

Comment: Well, what is your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` set to in `settings.py`? And where/how are you actually deploying? Your question is lacking a few details here ...

Comment: See here for info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'realwebsitename.com',
    'www.realwebsitename.com',
    'localhost',
]    -- This is my allowedhost list

Comment: And how are you serving this website?

Comment: GoDaddy is the hosting server

Comment: OK, then you probably need to add some GoDaddy IP address to that list would be my guess. Can't help you with what that might be. I wouldn't touch GoDaddy with a 10 foot pole ... ;)

Comment: I get these errors if i run the commnd >manage.py check --deploy

Comment: BTW, for serving a live site, I wouldn't use the `runserver`command ... you really should have something like `gunicorn` (if you're wsgi, something else if you're asgi).

Comment: Yes i have the wsgi.py file. How to use the command gunicorn?Can restore mysite to it initial state

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you definitely MUST NOT use `python manage.py runserver` command in production if you use it.
2. Instead of `python manage.py runserver` we use so-call wsgi application. You can think as first middleware (aha, there is second middleware) between you python code and browsers. The most popular `wsgi` apps: `uwsgi`, `gunicorn`.
3. After setup `WSGI` you need install and setup webserver (second middleware) between your code and browsers. The most popular webservers: `nginx`, `apache2`.

So, path to your server should look like:

```
Browser -> [Nginx -> gunicorn -> python code]
```

Everything that is in [square brackets] should be installed on your server(s).

Yes, it is a little bit complicated for the first time, and I would recommend using something like `Heroku` for deploying the first times.

Comment: Thanks. Website hosted already by another person. I was going to make changes to the website. Its hosted in godaddy .Is there  way i could restore my website? There is both asgi.py and wsgi.py in the folder

Comment: Just existing files `asgi.py` and `wsgi.py` is not enough, and they do not replace `uwsgi` application. I would recommend considering heroku as  start point, if you need to pickup it quickly.

Comment: Thanks ..i will set up the environment.

Comment: is it possible to install these Nginx -> gunicorn if im working from  a windows machine?